# Is it considered bad practice to use a static method as a factory?

Tags: oop, factory-pattern

I see most projects creating separate factory classes, so for example, they'll have a User class, and a UserFactory class. This makes sense if your factory needs more methods than just a CreateUser method, but most of these factories only have a constructor and a CreateUser method (or equivalent for whatever the factory creates). So, are there other reasons why you would create a separate factory class over just adding a static `User.create()` method to classes?

Comment: It makes all the difference for the strict pattern followers, but not that much in real life small projects. Appart from that, is aways a good practice to have a separate class that returns an interface based object. This can easy on your tests and any time you want to change the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, separate factory classes are mainly used if you often want to change the implementation, *especially for test cases*.  For example, if User has methods that hit a database and are "too slow" for a Unit Test, you might want to have a MockUser that doesn't use the database.  Then you can have a RealUserFactory for the actual app, and a MockUserFactory for the unit tests.

But there may be real world examples where you want to change, say from a SecurityClearedUser in your military spec app to a AnyOldUser in another.  So a config file would declare the class of the factory, e.g. a MilitaryUserFactory or an AnyOldFactory.

Of course, User.create() could read the actual class to create from a config file.  So, in practice, I'm not sure if there's that much of a difference.  Depends on how things are setup.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is 'separation of concerns'. In the case of User.Create, the user class will be doing more than it should, hence the need of a class that does precisely that, creating a User.

By using User.Create, you would have coupled the creation of an object to the class itself and in other instances, you will be confronted by scenarios were the user creation consists of various steps, and if that is the case, the User.Create method becomes inappropriate.

So to be brief, keep the user object responsible for being a user, and outsource the creation of the user to an external concern, Factory.

and from a readability perspective, User.Create vs UserFactory.Create... think of it as 'a car cannot create a car', but a factory can.